# Linear regression comparing sites and a predictors

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, interpretation, percentage

I have a small dataset of 11 different sites. At all sites, I have data collection annually varying in duration from only 2 years, up to 6 years for one site.
Annually, each site measures some "percentage" which in these data varies from 2 to 55%. I would like to test whether 2 predictors (A & Q) affect the percentage and whether these interact.

Because the different years of the sites are not independent I thought to use a random effect term to include all the data in one model.

My current code looks like this:

```
M1 <- lme(Percentage~ A, random=~1|SITE, data=data)
summary(M1)

M2 <- lme(Percentage~ Q, random=~1|SITE, data=data)
summary(M2)

M3 <- lme(Percentage~ A*Q, random=~1|SITE, data=data)
summary(M3)
```

The output of M3 is:

```
    Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: data 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  299.7651 309.0972 -143.8826

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | SITE
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    12.23643 7.630161

Fixed effects: Percentage ~ A * Q 
               Value Std.Error DF    t-value p-value
(Intercept)  9.36695  16.87529 25  0.5550690  0.5838
A           -0.04998   0.05152 25 -0.9701418  0.3413
Q           33.11042  39.52267 25  0.8377577  0.4101
A:Q          0.12382   0.11594 25  1.0680429  0.2957
```

Am I using the right way to include the random effect for this type of model, and therefore am I right to conclude that A and Q do not interact, as well as both do not affect the percentage?